# Error when trying to sync Gradle dependencies "Failed to resolve: redstone.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:1.1.1"

Tags: java, android, wordpress, gradle, xml-rpc

I'm building an android app that uses the wordpress-java library but I'm getting an `"Failed to resolve: redstone.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:1.1.1"` error.

**Build.Gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.paultoillion.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
 implementation 'net.bican:jwordpress:0.7.0'
}
```

implementation **net.bican:jwordpress:0.7.0** is what I added to include it in my project. I've tried all I can think of but can't seem to figure out the problem. I was able to get this to work in Intellij using Maven, but not in Android Studio using Gradle

Answer (score 0):

The library `redstone.xmlrpc:xmlrpc:1.1.1` is located into the [maven JBoss Repository Third party release](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/). (Searching on [MvnRepository](https://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/redstone.xmlrpc/xmlrpc/1.1.1), you can see the library location)

You can add this repository into your project `build.gradle` like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/'
        }
    }
}
```